# expand/contract container on hide/show animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I thought there was an easy way to make the container height fluid during an animation's resizing, but if so I've forgotten.  Before I do it programmatically, I thought I'd test me luck here.

The idea is that the bottom `<hr />` should gracefully move up/down as `#content` is animating, instead of snapping in place after the animation - *this is due to the `#container` not resizing*.

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/BZDbU/)

HTML:

```
<button id="trigger">trigger</button>
<hr />
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">foo
        <br />foo
        <br />foo
        <br />foo
        <br />foo
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
```

JS:

```
$('#trigger').click(function () {
    var $content = $('#content');
    if (!$content.hasClass('hidden')) {
        $content.stop(true, true).hide('drop', {
            easing: 'easeInQuad',
            direction: 'up'
        }, 'slow');
        $content.addClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $content.stop(true, true).show('drop', {
            easing: 'easeInQuad',
            direction: 'up'
        }, 'slow');
        $content.removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use `slideToggle` to resize your container to achieve this effect?

**jQuery**

```
$('#trigger').on('click', function() {
  var $content = $('#content');
  $content.slideToggle(1000);
});
```

[JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/4uLT2/1/)

Comment: good question, but no, `slideToggle` doesn't have the same fade effect.  Also, the `hr` is for demonstration purpose, taking the place of an element below; other content would naturally be in place of the `hr`

Comment: Cool, I'll remove the alternate example then. So you're looking to do 2 things then? 1) Fade effect from your original demo, and 2) resize the container so the elements after it animate up with it.

Comment: Whenever I begin to design something, I like to have options and let the end-user ultimately give input into what's best.  For that to happen, it'd be ideal if this worked with any animation -- imagine left floated content and the animation going from right to left. In this particular case `slideToggle` is probably a nice fallback, but a `swing`, or a `drop` would be ideal.  I thought that I had solved this before, so I'll have to look into my repertoire of code, perhaps I chained animations, or did a callback during.  I asked here because I thought it'd be an easy CSS solution.

Comment: I'd be interested to see your answer if you do find it. My challenge with `.hide()` is that it doesn't affect the height, rather the y-coordinates of the element (in the case of your particular application), hence your need for a container. And of course, once it has been removed from the view, it has a `display: none`, so chaining a `slideToggle`, or subsequent effect on `content` would be useless. So you're on to something with the container, as the animation should occur on `container` subsequently.

Comment: Here it is (working?) with CSS, but you need a hardcoded height for your container class, otherwise the transition won't fire: http://jsfiddle.net/eXcHq/

Comment: That's not working on the up/hide part, but I've answered this with animate.  Still a shame can't get this to work with `drop`

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/BZDbU/2/)

Thought there'd be a CSS solution.  Instead, it looks like animate works; however, it's a simple slide/fade, and doesn't use `drop`:

```
$('#trigger').click(function () {
    var $content = $('#content');
    if (!$content.hasClass('hidden')) {
        $content.stop(true,true).animate({height:'hide',opacity:'hide'},'slow','easeInQuad');
        $content.addClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $content.stop(true,true).animate({height:'show',opacity:'show'},'slow','easeInQuad');
        $content.removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```